# How to load data from one project's bucket into another project's table in python?

Tags: python, google-bigquery, google-cloud-storage

I have two projects. I store data in `project_A` and build tables in `project_B`. I have created a `service_account.json` for both of them, but I don't know how to use  both files at the same time when I need to load the data from `project_A` and build the tables in `project_B`.

The data is stored in URI:

```
gs://project_A//*
```

The table will live in `project_B` table name `huge_table`

```
from google import storage, bigquery

proj_a_client =  storage.Client.from_service_account_json(service_acct_A.json)
proj_b_client = bigquery.Client.from_service_account_json(service_acct_B.json)

dest_table = proj_b_client.dataset('DS_B').table('huge_table')
uri = 'gs://project_A//*'

job_config = bigquery.LoadJobConfig()
load_job = proj_b_client.load_table_from_uri(uri,
                                         dest_table,
                                         job_config=job_config)
```

But I get the error:

> google.api_core.exceptions.Forbidden: 403 Access Denied: File
>   gs://project_A/: Access Denied

Comment: At which point are you getting the error? By the looks of your code, it seems that the service account from Project B is the one trying to access the Cloud Storage bucket, could you please confirm this? Also, a full trace of it would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to make sure `service_acct_B` has storage access to `project_A`:

In `project_A`,

- go to `IAM & admin`
- add member `service_acct_B` with (at a minimum) `Storage Object Viewer` role

As a matter of fact, you don't use/need a `service_acct_A` here so 
`proj_a_client =  storage.Client.from_service_account_json(service_acct_A.json)` is redundant.